# Count and sort XML nodes based on first part of an attribute

Tags: xslt-1.0

This is my first post to this excellent forum which has helped me
to find answers to many different questions. I take my hat off to all of you.
Now to my problem. I have a fragment of XML and a fragment of a stylesheet for Excel.
The GeneralRelation nodes describes the relation between two objects whose id's are in the attribute relatedRefs. The id's represent a part and a vendor. I want to find the greatest number of vendors related to a part (in this case two) to define the correct number of header columns. The code I have written (could it be simplified?) works for the case when the nodes are sorted on the relatedRefs attribute (all relations from one part are in sequence). 
How could I write the code to cover the case when the nodes are not sorted?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PLMXML >
  <GeneralRelation id="id26" subType="VMRepresents" relatedRefs="#id13 #id19">
  </GeneralRelation>
  <GeneralRelation id="id61" subType="VMRepresents" relatedRefs="#id51 #id54">
  </GeneralRelation>
  <GeneralRelation id="id37" subType="VMRepresents" relatedRefs="#id13 #id30">
  </GeneralRelation>
</PLMXML>
```

Stylesheet

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">progid="Excel.Sheet"    </xsl:processing-instruction>
          <Row>
        <!-- Vendor header -->
            <xsl:variable name="generalRelationList" select="/PLMXML/GeneralRelation[@subType='VMRepresents']"/>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="count($generalRelationList) = 1">
                <Cell >
                  <Data >Vendor [1]    </Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell >
                  <Data >Vendor part [1]    </Data>
                </Cell>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="count($generalRelationList) &gt; 1">
                <xsl:variable name="startrel">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$generalRelationList[1]/@relatedRefs"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="startid">
                  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($startrel,' ')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:call-template name="get-max-vendors">
                  <xsl:with-param name="pGenrellist" select="$generalRelationList"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="pMaxvend" select="1"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="pCurrmaxvend" select="1"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="pPrevid" select="$startid"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="pListpos" select="2"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </Row>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="get-max-vendors">
    <xsl:param name="pGenrellist"/>
    <xsl:param name="pMaxvend"/>
    <xsl:param name="pCurrmaxvend"/>
    <xsl:param name="pPrevid"/>
    <xsl:param name="pListpos"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- Output vendor columns -->
      <xsl:when test="$pListpos = count($pGenrellist)">
        <xsl:variable name="reldata2" select="$pGenrellist[$pListpos]/@relatedRefs"/>
        <xsl:variable name="actid2" select="substring-before($reldata2,' ')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$pCurrmaxvend &lt; $pMaxvend">
            <xsl:call-template name="print-vendor-headers">
              <xsl:with-param name="pNo_of_vendors" select="$pMaxvend"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pNvendor" select="$pMaxvend"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="($pCurrmaxvend &gt; $pMaxvend or $pCurrmaxvend = $pMaxvend) and $pPrevid = $actid2">
            <xsl:call-template name="print-vendor-headers">
              <xsl:with-param name="pNo_of_vendors" select="$pCurrmaxvend + 1"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pNvendor" select="$pCurrmaxvend + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="print-vendor-headers">
              <xsl:with-param name="pNo_of_vendors" select="$pCurrmaxvend"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pNvendor" select="$pCurrmaxvend"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$pListpos &lt; count($pGenrellist)">
        <xsl:variable name="reldata" select="$pGenrellist[$pListpos]/@relatedRefs"/>
        <xsl:variable name="actid" select="substring-before($reldata,' ')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$actid = $pPrevid">
            <xsl:call-template name="get-max-vendors">
              <xsl:with-param name="pGenrellist" select="$pGenrellist"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pMaxvend" select="$pMaxvend"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pCurrmaxvend" select="$pCurrmaxvend + 1"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pPrevid" select="$actid"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pListpos" select="$pListpos + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$actid != $pPrevid and $pCurrmaxvend &gt; $pMaxvend">
            <xsl:call-template name="get-max-vendors">
              <xsl:with-param name="pGenrellist" select="$pGenrellist"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pMaxvend" select="$pCurrmaxvend"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pCurrmaxvend" select="1"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pPrevid" select="$actid"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pListpos" select="$pListpos + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="get-max-vendors">
              <xsl:with-param name="pGenrellist" select="$pGenrellist"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pMaxvend" select="$pMaxvend"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pCurrmaxvend" select="1"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pPrevid" select="$actid"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pListpos" select="$pListpos + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="print-vendor-headers">
    <!-- Number of vendors to be printed -->
    <xsl:param name="pNo_of_vendors"/>
    <xsl:param name="pNvendor"/>
    <xsl:if test="$pNvendor &gt; 0">
      <Cell >
        <Data >Vendor [    <xsl:value-of select="$pNo_of_vendors - $pNvendor + 1"/>]    </Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell >
        <Data >Vendor part [    <xsl:value-of select="$pNo_of_vendors - $pNvendor + 1"/>]    </Data>
      </Cell>
      <!-- Recursive call decrementing the number of vendors to
           be printed -->
      <xsl:call-template name="print-vendor-headers">
        <xsl:with-param name="pNo_of_vendors" select="$pNo_of_vendors"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pNvendor" select="$pNvendor - 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Row>
  <Cell>
    <Data>Vendor [1]</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data>Vendor part [1]</Data>
  </Cell>
</Row>
```

Desired result (and result if input is sorted)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Row>
  <Cell>
    <Data>Vendor [1]</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data>Vendor part [1]</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data>Vendor [2]</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data>Vendor part [2]</Data>
  </Cell>
</Row>
```

Thanks to @michael.hor257k. Following his advice I came up with the following stylesheet.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="part-group" match="/PLMXML/GeneralRelation" use="substring-before(@relatedRefs,' ')"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Row>
      <xsl:for-each select="/PLMXML/GeneralRelation[generate-id() = generate-id(key('part-group', substring-before(@relatedRefs,' '))[1])]">
        <xsl:sort select="count(key('part-group', substring-before(@relatedRefs,' ')))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:variable name="nVendors" select="key('part-group', substring-before(@relatedRefs,' '))"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
          <Cell>
            <xsl:value-of select="count($nVendors)"/>
          </Cell>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Row>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which gives the following result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Row>
  <Cell>2</Cell>
</Row>
```

Now when I know the max I just call my other template to get my headers.

Comment: Could you explain the logic that needs to be applied here, in simple words? I don't understand how one would get your desired result from the given input, if doing this manually.

Comment: In the example there are three relations defined. Two of them relate a Part with id=id13 to different Vendors (with id=id19 and id30). The other one relates a Part with id=id51 to a Vendor with id59.

Comment: So the first id is a part and the other id is a vendor? And IIUC you want to group the relations by part? I still don't see how that leads to your output: you have part #13 with 2 vendors, and part #51 with one vendor. How does that fit into one row with 4 cells?

Comment: In the example there are three relations defined. Two of them relate a Part with id=id13 to different Vendors (with id=id19 and id30). The other one relates a Part with id=id51 to a Vendor with id59. Find the maximum number of Vendors related to a Part and generate that number of columns to the header in the sheet. In this case the maximum number is 2. The part with id13 is related to 2 Vendors. The Vendor columns in the output is part of a BOM line represented in Excel and the must not be any blank columns. There could be hundreds of GeneralRelation nodes.

Comment: The will be two columns for each Vendor (different attributes).

Comment: I still don't get the final output bit. Anyway, you can [group](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) the relations by part and sort the groups by their size, descending. The number of vendors in the first group is the maximum number of vendors for any part.